# Positioning of 2 divs side by side each of width 50%

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have 3 divs inside a container. I want the first div to take up 100% width and the other dive to be of 50% and lie side by side below the first div. however if i give 50% width and float:left to other 2 divs, the 3rd div is going below the 2nd one. I tried with overflow and position also but could not get it to work.

CSS:

```
 .contentC{
        /*width:100%;*/
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    #box1 {
        background:#f00;
        float:left;
        width:100%;

    }

    #box2 {
        background:#0f0;
        float:left;
        width:50%;
    }
    #box3 {
        background:#055;
        float:left;
        width:50%;

    }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class ="contentC">
    <div id="box1">Hi,Div1</div>
    <div id="box2">Hi,Div2</div>
    <div id="box3">Hi,Div3</div>
</div>
</body>
```

I've also tried with `clearfix` and `overflow` but could not get it working.

Comment: Your code works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/9qCGE/

Comment: Which browser are you seeing this error in?

Comment: Thank you folks...will keep working and get involved in SO ...thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all margin and padding from box2 and box3 via padding: 0; margin: 0;

Comment: Well the code he implemented at the top works fine, so probably it's something with the parent divs padding or margin, not the box2 and box3. Good thinking.

Comment: Thanks, just noticed your fiddle. I checked it in IE and it was working fine there too, so I'm not sure what the issue is in OP unless he has some other css that is applying a margin/padding from higher in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the context or what its doing that is unexpected, but what you have is correct sans a left float on the first div.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8n4Qx/

```
#box1 {
    background:#f00;
    width:100%;
}
```